# "in any situation" vs. "at any time"

Tags: prepositions

[From Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ever)

> ever: at any time

> If **ever** there was a cause for celebration, this peace treaty was it.

Could I interpret "at any time" as "**in** any situation" or "**for** any situation"? If yes, which one should I go with?

Answer (score -1):

Neither phrase is, to me, an apt replacement for the word “ever” in your example sentence. The two phrases mean essentially the same thing, but a context other than your example sentence could favor one over the other. “This type of torque wrench should be suitable for any situation you are likely to encounter.” “I can envision those shoes working well for you in just about any situation.”

You could swap the pronouns in my two example sentences without changing the meaning of the sentences.